# How can I request microphone, camera permission on WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, android-permissions

In the manifests.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
```

And my activity.

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val wv: WebView by lazy {
        findViewById<WebView>(R.id.wv)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view)

        init()
    }

    private fun init(){

        wv.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
        wv.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        setUpWebViewDefaults(wv)
        wv.loadUrl("https://com.example")

        wv.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest) {
                runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                    if (request.origin.toString() == "https://com.example/") {
                        request.grant(request.resources)
                    } else {
                        request.deny()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpWebViewDefaults(webView: WebView) {
        val settings = webView.settings

        // Enable Javascript
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
        settings.useWideViewPort = true
        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true

        // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
        settings.builtInZoomControls = true

        // Allow use of Local Storage
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
        settings.displayZoomControls = false

        // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        // AppRTC requires third party cookies to work
        val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
    }
}
```

This doesn't show the permission popup.

Comment: Does the current URL you are loading needs those permissions? I feel it will popup on a website which needs the permissions. I might be wrong.

Comment: Of course, not this URI. And I thought so but it doesn't ask. @che